# How to use conditional compilation in Cargo.toml for lib?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust implementation using `lib` defined in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

I have an alternate implementation specific to Linux OS `src/lib_linux.rs`. I would like to use it via `Cargo.toml` via conditional compilation with `cfg` keyword:

```ini
[lib.'cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))']
path = "src/lib.rs"

[lib.'cfg(target_os = "linux")']
path = "src/lib_linux.rs"
```

I know that at the present time (Rust 1.74.0), it is not possible to use `cfg` keyword in `Cargo.toml` for `lib` => see https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/12260

Have you a solution for my problem ? I don't want to use conditional compilation with `cfg(target_os = "linux")` in `src/lib.rs` (too many duplicate lines with `cfg`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your current `lib.rs` and `lib_linux.rs` to something else like `impl.rs` and `impl_linux.rs`.

Then, conditionally define and reexport from those modules:

```rust
// lib.rs

#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
mod impl;
#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
pub use impl::*;

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
mod impl_linux;
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
pub use impl_linux::*;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works as expected :)

Comment: @lcheylus make sure you accept the answer when you get a chance

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept your answer => Done